# Load infile statement throws error

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a table where i am trying to insert data from a text file but it throws some error
the command is

```
mysql -u user -p<pwd> -h <server> --local-infile bsm -sse LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/file.txt' INTO table test_jan2 FIELDS terminated by '|' LINES terminated by '\n' (value1,value2,value3) set id = NULL;
```

the error it throws is

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

the table structure is

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| value1      | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| value2    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| value3 | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_created  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```bsh
$ mysql -u user -p<pwd> -h <server> --local-infile bsm -e \
   "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/file.txt'
    INTO table test_jan2
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (value1,value2,value3)"
```